# Navigating between Pages in XAML and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to make a simple game for `windows-phone 8.1` but I am facing trouble navigating between Pages. I have a `MainPage` from where I navigate to `GameOver` Page. In `GameOver` Page, I have a button `Play Again` which navigate me back to the `MainPage`. Now when I return back after clicking on button, I want the `MainPage` to restart as if it was starting for the first time. But instead, it resumes with the modified state. What can I do so that upon reaching back to a Page, it starts all over again?

Comment: would the `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` work for you?  I'm actually trying to remove the previous journal entry and this didn't work for me, but it did cause me to lose the associated state.

Comment: Please update your code here

Comment: You can check the condition like this within `OnNavigatedTo()`... `if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)          {  // your code                                                                                                                 }`

Answer (score 0):

setting the mainpage to a new instance of the mainpage before navigating to it should work.

Comment: Can I do this from my navigated Page i.e. can I set the `mainpage` from `GameOver` Page?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a itemControl over your main grid and then just hide it when not needed

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Page1.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative));
```

Passing unique parameters forces a new instance of the page and if you wanna remove any previous instances use this

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your page is set to be cached. In the page's constructor try setting the page's NavigationCacheMode property to Disabled.